# How can you convert an array of floats to array of integers in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

i've been trying to write a simple car game where if car ride outside of track it will start from the beginning. I was trying to do this by pixel perfect collision in pygame but i had a problem that it wants integers but i did the whole code on floats.
How can I convert array of float to array of integers?
Here is a code https://github.com/wisniea/CarAI/tree/master/Car%20AI
And there is an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOz1B.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack OverFlow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to ask a question that will get good responses. Please post your code here and not a link to your code in git hub.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: I've tried using rint() method from numpy library but it didnt help :(

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a problem specification.  Again, see "How to Ask".

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) (or [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) if you want rounding rather than truncating) to all elements of a list:

```py
x = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
x = list(map(int, x))  # [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: or `[int(v) for v in x]`

Comment: nice. for some reason didnt think of list comprehension

Comment: I think OP wants rounding not truncating. But it's minor

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
list(map(lambda f: int(f), [4.12, 4.32, 23.43]))
```

Comment: More concise: list(map(int, [4.12, 4.32, 23.43]))